# log4J empty file

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j

i have configured log4j appender to create log file every hour. The logged file should not be created if there is nothing to log.

Everything works correctly, but when I start jBoss the log file is created even if there is nothing to log.

Appender settings.

```
<appender name="ordersLogFile" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
    <rollingPolicy name="ordersLogFile" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
         <param name="FileNamePattern" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/Portal_%d{yyyy_MM_dd-HH}-00-00.log" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="'%d{yyyyMMddHHmmss,SSS}';%m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Is it possible to turn off creation of log file during jboss start?